# Paypal integration hidden values

Tags: php, security, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am using paypal for checkout on my website using PHP. Its working fine but I have one concern. As I am not using on site checkout so I go to paypal website for checkout so I have to pass hidden values. As the amount is also sent using hidden value so If someone changes the amount using firebug and then go to paypal then he will be able to pay that amount. I am handling this issue in notify url to verify the payment but is there anyway to do this without sending hidden variables? I know user is changing the values so if he pays thats his headache that his money will be for nothing as I am verifying in notify url but I want the site to prevent going to checkout. Similarly receiver email can be changed as well, I am verifying this also on notify url but this is critical, it should not allow.

Consider If I am the user, I have two paypal accounts, I change to my one paypal email in firebug, I enter price $1 and checkout using my second email and if someone hasn't verified on the backend it I will get that product for free. Or if I only change the amount, I will get the product for $1.

What is the way around? I want my site not go to the checkout page if any value is changed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Save the prices in your own database. Compare the money paid with the price in your database. This way you can detect edited payments and cancel them.

Comment: I am doing same, but I want aksed that "I want my site not go to the checkout page if any value is changed". I guess thats not possible

Answer (score 0):

To prevent users from changing hidden values or URL variables I normally pass a hash and verify it before processing.

```
I.e. 

//Combine values that you want to protect and create a hash.
$email = 'someone@domain.com';
$cost = 15;
$hash = sha1(md5($email.$cost.'some-secret-key'));

On the other page I will verify the hash,

$hash = sha1(md5($_REQUEST['email'].$_REQUEST['cost'].'some-secret-key'));

if($_REQUEST['hash'] != $hash){
      echo 'Values changed';
      exit();
}
```

You can pass the hash into URL, POST, Form Hidden variables or SESSION. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am verifying email and cost but I like your approach, but lets say user changes the value, he will be able to pay.. I want to prevent user to go to checkout page, as I am doing it on paypal's site so only method is to use hidden values, I think thats the only way around to verify it

Comment: The workaround that I tried was to go someother page and if values are correct then redirect (auto submit) to checkout page but in some browsers like firefox it gives warning that "you are being redirected."

Comment: @Hamza You need to add a page before the checkout. On this page you will verify the hash. If hash don't match you display an error other wise there will be a hidden form on this page which you will submit with javascript. So all your values will be checked and posted to paypal.

Comment: @Hamza On this page you can also show a message like "Please wait ... processing your request" and then in the background submit the form on page load using JavaScript.